How to stop Skype for Mac from automatically updating
I'd like to know definitive techniques for preventing the modern 2024 versions of Skype from automatically notifiying the user about software updates.
This happens even mid-call several times a month. I can't stand it!
I'm using Skype v8.120.0.207 on an M1 MacBook Air running MacOS 14.5.
All suggestions in the answers I've found in apple.stackexchange and superuser.stackexchange are out of date.
Is there a solution using HOSTS file, or Little Snitch, or something else?
I would rather have Skype fail to connect because the version is out of date, than interrupt calls with software updates. Please put me out of my misery.

I'm trying Lulu. It's a free port blocker a bit like Little Snitch. I've added a block on get.skype.com to the Skype App, Skype Helper and Skype Renderer... Will report back whether it works...
